# Is there something similar to case statement but returns multiple rows that can be used in SELECT query?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, select

Based on the input 'include_child' can I choose the where condition?

Actual query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
WHERE t.node_id IN (SELECT decode(:include_Child , 1 ,child_node_id, 0 , 123) 
                             FROM table2 
                            WHERE node_id IN 123 )
```

Looking for something like:

```
IF include_Child = 0 then
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
WHERE t.node_id IN 123 -- do no use table2 at all

-- only when condition met then use table2
IF include_Child = 1 then
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
WHERE t.node_id IN (select child_node from table2)
```

I want this in a SELECT query.Not in PL/SQL blocks. DB version is 11g

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

How about using `and` and `or`?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE (:include_Child = 0 and t.node_id = 123) or
      (:include_Child = 1 and t.node_id IN (select child_node from table2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

and here's the other way to do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.node_id IN 123 -- do no use table2 at all
AND include_Child = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.node_id IN (select child_node from table2)
AND include_Child = 1
```